# How to create square thumnail by css that can relatively with all images and thumbnail sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display any images size as a square thumbnail by using css without cropping it before.
For example I have any size of an images that's x and y dimension if x less than y that means size of square thumbnail is x otherwise is y.
Here's simple picture that i try to explain.

[image: Here's simple picture that i try to explain]

I found the solution by use this CSS conmand

```
background-image: url(images/1000004_234262146740874_1109821750_n.jpg);
background-size: cover;
```

But i don't want to do like this because i want to use **img** html tag, and i don't want to check an image size because i want to use only css.

Here's my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/K7pje/. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's an update to your fiddle with a solution for portrait images.  Unfortunately there is no way to do the same for landscape without using JavaScript.

http://jsfiddle.net/K7pje/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="container-working">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <img src="http://www.pa.msu.edu/people/frenchj/moon/moon-6day-1822.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-working {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    border: 3px solid #03F;
}

.inner-container {
    position: relative;
    top: -50%;
}

.inner-container img {
    margin-top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sPg73/) in which there is a large background image (the full image is the upper one).

The two images below decrease the size of the div, and then reposition the image within the div.

CSS

```
.clippeddiv {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/JLEPxT2.jpg');
    background-position: 65% 35%
}
```